# FFmpeg Convert to JPEG works in VLC but not in Mac Preview?

Tags: image, ffmpeg, jpeg, preview

I'm trying to convert a PNG image to a JPEG image using ffmpeg. As far as I can tell, it's working fine, but it doesn't display properly in Mac Preview.

I'm running the following:

```
$ ffmpeg -i foo.png foo.jpg
```

And it produces the following output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'foo.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 200x231, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7ffeaf00ae00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'foo.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc), 200x231, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=3.7 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed= 4.7x    
video:12kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

When I open `foo.jpg` in most applications, such as VLC or Google Chrome, I get exactly what I expected: an image that looks exactly the same as `foo.png`, the input.

[image: <code>foo.png</code> (input)]
[image: <code>foo.jpg</code> (output)]

However, this is what is displayed in the Finder preview, and the same this is displayed when I open up the file in "Preview."

[image: the problem]

~~~I wonder if this has something to do with the `deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly` error, but I'm not sure, especially since the image is fine, the problem seems to be elsewhere.~~~

It seems the `deprecated pixel format` error is not the issue (that's an internal thing), so I guess I just need to specify pixel formats properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like QT / AVFoundation doesn't like fully-sampled chroma in JPEG.

First try

```
ffmpeg -i foo.png -pix_fmt yuvj422p foo.jpg
```

else,

```
ffmpeg -i foo.png -pix_fmt yuvj420p foo.jpg
```

The warning about deprecated format relates to ffmpeg internals and not the produced output.

Comment: I presume this is related to why I always have to use `-pix_fmt yuv420p` when making videos to be compatible with QuickTime? Do you know what difference your additional `j` makes please?

Comment: `j` stands for `jpeg`. Normal YUV (in videos) is limited range: 16-235, whereas for JPEGs, it's full range 0-255.

Comment: I see. Thanks for taking time to explain.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like both work, though based on your order I'll stick to `yuvj244p`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in, Apple-supplied `sips` *"Scriptable Image Processing System"* tool to do the conversion and thereby avoid the issue and also be less dependent on having to install external tools:

```
sips -s format jpeg input.png --out output.jpg
```

Comment: That's a good option, too, but since I already have ffmpeg installed and use it for audio/video conversions, I'd rather stick with ffmpeg than learn a new tool.